# Java Client/Server application

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a multithread server, waiting for socket connections.

The first exchange of message is always of the same type, the clients sends an object with the authentication details(userid/pwd), the server checks it and reply to the server if the authentication has been passed or not.

After this first exchange of messages, the client will send some requests, corresponding to  various tasks the server is able to execute. 
How do i model those eterogeneous requests? In particular my question regards the type of object sent between client and server with InputObjecStream/OutputObjectStream

I had 2 ideas:

1. Using a  "generic message" object, with 2 attributes: a task identifier and an HashMap without generics,  able to carry various type of parameters requested for executing the task.
2. An object for every type of task, this solution is "cleaner", but I don't know how to make the server understand the type of the message received, I thought about a series of object casting of the received message from the client to every possible "specific task message",  ignoring the many CastException. It sounds just bad, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: If you choose route 2, use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is very generic but will be hard to maintain. After a while you'll notice that you no longer remember what kind of objects should be in this generic map. You'll have to keep the dictionary in sync.

The second approach is much better. Essentially you receive an abstract `Request` object with various subclasses. The base class can hold some general information. Normally you would use polymorphism and implement the action in each subclass, overriding abstract method from `Request` class. But you can't because request object would have to hold server-side logic.

The best you can do here is [visitor](/questions/tagged/visitor) [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). With it, for the price of slightly obscuring your code, you'll get very generic and safe design. `instanceof` tends to be ugly after some time.

Comment: I just read something on the Visitor pattern, I never used it before, in your design the Visitor should be the methods that handle the message and execute the task while the Visited Element is the message?

Comment: @mark: yes, abstract `Request` class has `accept(visitor)` method and concrete visitor implements different handler methods based on real `Request` type. No subclassing and `instanceof` required.

Comment: Since I need just 1 concrete visitor with a lot of overloading visit() methods, should I avoid the visitor interface and work directly with the concrete visitor? It seems useless to me

Comment: @mark: yes, there is no point in having `Visitor` interface and concrete implementation. You can split them once you need them.

Answer (score 2):

Why not combine the two ideas

Start with a common level interface that the server can cast to determine what it should do or now to react.

As the object is passed off to the handler responsible for handling te request can further cast the object (based on a deeper level of interface implementation)

IMHO

Comment: nice idea, I really like it: it sounds simplier than the Visitor pattern, requiring only 1 additional interface instead of 2 (Element & Visitor)

I'm going to read a bit more stuff on visitor design pattern, but I think I'm gonna use this solution

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use `XML` messages for the communication. You could prepend in the first bytes an indication for which `XML` object the message should be mapped and on reception of the message, just check these bytes find the indicator, and use the rest bytesequence to marshal the bytes to XML object (using `JAXB` or `SimpleXML` or `DOM` or anyother xml parser) XML is very verbose and you could use it here to encapsulate your messages.